Determine downstream temperature of (upstream) saturated liquid -- problem underspecified?
I was given the following problem as a pop quiz:

You have liquid nitrogen in a container, in a saturated liquid state,
at known pressure P1. It flows through an orifice to known pressure
P2. How would you find the downstream temperature?

This is all the known information.
I asked if I could assume adiabatic and/or isothermal and was told "I had to calculate that". My best guess is I am either supposed to assume 1) it remains saturated liquid (seems a bad assumption to me), or 2) the flow is isenthalpic? Intuitively that strikes me as more justifiable, but I can't quite articulate why.
Now I have a vague recollection of solving this exact problem in undergrad thermo, so I am probably missing something obvious, but I don't quite see how to fix the second state. Is this problem under-specified? If not, what should I know or assume in order to solve it?

assume the initial condition is static, take the vapor at initial condition, expand it to the new one.   Look up a refrigeration cycle for reference.

It's liquid at location 1. I know cycles (or at least I thought I did), that's why I feel like I would need to know something else about the process from 1 to 2 (and to be clear, this problem isn't necessarily literally part of a cycle). With P2 < P1 (as it must be), the fluid drops down into the vapor dome, I get that. I guess I could assume the flow is isentropic? How would I justify that?

Saturated means at vapor pressure.
